# Heteroskedasticity correction

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, heteroscedasticity

After I ran a bptest and I detected heteroskedasticity, I want to correct for it.

What is the difference between the functions HC1, HC2 and HC3 in R?

bptest(model2)
model3 <- coeftest(model2, vcov. = vcovHC(model2, type = "HC3"))

Comment: Apparently "HC" gives White's estimator, so the answer is hidden somewhere in `MacKinnon J. G., White H. (1985), Some heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix estimators with improved finite sample properties. Journal of Econometrics 29, 305-325`.